# How to match Regex except some words in google sheets apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, re2

I the following code in my google sheets apps script file. I want to match all strings that match '10.10.23 ' followed by any word except 'No' and 'Skip'. So the expected results are:

**Expected Output:**
10.10.23 Yes,
10.10.23 Need this,
10.10.23 wanted

**Should not show these:**
second 10.10.23 No,
10.10.23 Skip paras

```
function TestRegex(){

    var data = "first 10.10.23 Yes\nsecond 10.10.23 No\n\n10.10.23 Skip paras\n10.10.23 Need this 10.10.23 wanted";
    var regexPattern = `\\b10\\.10\\.23\\b\\ *(?!.*(No|Skip)\\b)\\w+/g`;

    var regExp = new RegExp(regexPattern, "gi"); // "gi" global & case-insensitive
    var result = regExp.exec(data);

    Logger.log(`result: ${result}`);
    Logger.log(`result.Length: ${result.length()}`);

}
```

I tried almost every way with no results. It seems like there is no lookback in regex of RE2, so any workaround to do this? Also, please provide any link to test the regex online that will work with google sheets apps script.